# Searching for duplicate values in a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, search, area

I am figuring a method to search the duplicated parts in a 2D array.

Taking the below array for example:

```
 1    2    3    4    5
 6    7    8    9   10
11   12   13   14   15
16   17   18   19   20
21   22   23   24   25
26    *8    9*   29   30
31   *13   14   15*   35
17   *18   19*   39   40
41   *23   24*   44   45
46   47   48   49   50
```

Is there any method can automatically search the duplicated areas and save the coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> l=[[1,    2,    3,    4,    5],
... [6,    7,    8,    9,   10],
... [11,   12,   13,   14,   15],
... [16,   17,   18,   19,   20],
... [21,   22,   23,   24,   25],
... [26,    8,    9,   29,   30],
... [31,   13,   14,   15,   35],
... [17,   18,   19,   39,   40],
... [41,   23,   24,   44,   45],
... [46,   47,   48,   49,   50]]
>>> seen = set()
>>> dupes = {}
>>> for i_index, i in enumerate(l):
...     for j_index, j in enumerate(i):
...         if j in seen:
...             dupes[(i_index, j_index)] = j
...         seen.add(j)
...
>>> for coord, num in dupes.iteritems():
...     print "%s: %s" % (coord, num)
...
(7, 0): 17
(8, 2): 24
(7, 1): 18
(8, 1): 23
(6, 1): 13
(6, 3): 15
(6, 2): 14
(5, 1): 8
(5, 2): 9
(7, 2): 19
```

Comment: does this work if there for coordinates if there are multiple repeated items?

Comment: @RyanSaxe The dictionary key is the coordinate pair, so the entire array could be filled with the same value and it'd save each coordinate pair after the first as a separate item in the dupes dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a collections.counter of all of the previous entries. As you iterate through the array, check if each element already exists in the counter class, if it does, append the coordinates to a list, and keep going. If it doesn't, increment the counter on that specific number.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `dict`, where key is the number and store it's co-ordinates inside a list.

```
In [171]: lis
Out[171]: 
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
 [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
 [21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
 [26, 8, 9, 29, 30],
 [31, 13, 14, 15, 35],
 [17, 18, 19, 39, 40],
 [41, 23, 24, 44, 45],
 [46, 47, 48, 49, 50]]

In [172]: from collections import defaultdict

In [173]: dic=defaultdict(list)

In [174]: for i,x in enumerate(lis):
    for j,y in enumerate(x):
        dic[y].append((i,j))
   .....:         

In [175]: for num,coords in dic.items():
    if len(coords)>1:
        print "{0} was repeated at coordinates {1}".format(num,
                                             " ".join(str(x) for x in coords))
   .....:         
8 was repeated at coordinates (1, 2) (5, 1)
9 was repeated at coordinates (1, 3) (5, 2)
13 was repeated at coordinates (2, 2) (6, 1)
14 was repeated at coordinates (2, 3) (6, 2)
15 was repeated at coordinates (2, 4) (6, 3)
17 was repeated at coordinates (3, 1) (7, 0)
18 was repeated at coordinates (3, 2) (7, 1)
19 was repeated at coordinates (3, 3) (7, 2)
23 was repeated at coordinates (4, 2) (8, 1)
24 was repeated at coordinates (4, 3) (8, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, it not only has to look for a single duplicated value, but any series of values. i.e with `[1,2,3,4]` it would find a duplicate of `[2,3,4]` in say `[39,87,2,3,4]`.

Imports and test values

```
import itertools,pprint
from collections import defaultdict
l = ((1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
 (6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
 (11, 12, 13, 14, 15),
 (16, 17, 18, 19, 20),
 (21, 22, 23, 24, 25),
 (26, 8, 9, 29, 30),
 (31, 13, 14, 15, 35),
 (17, 18, 19, 39, 40),
 (41, 23, 24, 44, 45),
 (46, 47, 48, 49, 50))
```

Main code:

```
seen = defaultdict(dict)
for y,row in enumerate(l):
        rowlen = len(row)
        values = [ [ (row[i:k+1]) for (i,k) in zip(range(rowlen),range(e,rowlen,1))] for e in range(rowlen) ]
        for valueGroup in values:
            for x,value in enumerate(valueGroup):
                seen[value]['count'] = seen[value].get('count',0) + 1
                seen[value]['x-coOrd'] = x
                seen[("R",y)][value] = True

for y in range(len(l)):
    my_rows_vals = seen[("R",y)].keys()
    for value in my_rows_vals:
        if seen[value]['count'] > 1:
            print "{0} repeated at ({1},{2})".format(value,seen[value]['x-coOrd'],y)
```

Will output, as a sample (there was more output):

```
(13, 14) repeated at (1,6)
(14, 15) repeated at (2,6)
(13,) repeated at (1,6)
(13, 14, 15) repeated at (1,6)
(14,) repeated at (2,6)
(17, 18) repeated at (0,7)
(18, 19) repeated at (1,7)
(17,) repeated at (0,7)
(18,) repeated at (1,7)
(19,) repeated at (2,7)
(17, 18, 19) repeated at (0,7)
(23,) repeated at (1,8)
(24,) repeated at (2,8)
(23, 24) repeated at (1,8)
```

The list comprehension logic was reasoned based of this example

```
 l = [1,2,3,4]
 len = 4
 i:k
 0:1 1:2 2:3 3:4  i = 0,1,2,len-e  k = e,e+1,e+2,e+3    e = 0
 0:2 1:3 2:4      i = 0,1,len-e    k = e,e+1,e+2        e = 1
 0:3 1:4          i = 0,len-e      k = e,e+1            e = 2
 0:4              i = len-e        k = e                e = 3
```

This method is different to the other answers, as it checks for both individual and *sequences* of numbers, and highlights both parties involved in the match.